# 2D BufferedImage colors stored in 1D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bufferedimage

The `setRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int)` method in `BufferedImage` uses a 1D array to represent a 2D object (the image's colors). How does this work? How can I access such an array (the 1D one) using x/y coordinates?

Comment: The array is a single series of `int` which is `width` x `height` long.  What you need to do is detemine the index represented by the x/y position by using something like `y * width + x`. So if the image is 20 pixels wide, x/y = 0x1 = 20 (because the array is zero index), the second row (y = 2) would be 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1D array contains lines of 2D image concatenated. 
In the simplest way you can compute offset of the pixel as: `x + (y * width)`.

E.g. an image:

```
.X.
XXX
X.X
```

could would be stored as

```
.X.XXXX.X
```

In `BufferedImage` it is actually more dificult, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)),  the index to array is computed as `offset + (y-startY)*scansize + (x-startX)`

Comment: How would I get the width and height of an array like that?

Comment: The array have `size width*height`, but just knowing the size of array, `width` and `height` cannot be determined. E.g. having array of size 15, it can represent an image of size 3x5 or 5x3 and you cannot tell. You have to store image dimensions as an extra information next to the array with image data.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks, though.